# How to make aar in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I have the following build.gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

   lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':olympus-commons')
    compile project(':stream-client')
    compile project(':door-proxy')

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'

    compile 'to.talk.aragorn:logging:0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'
    compile 'to.talk.aragorn:event-utils:0.1-SNAPSHOT@aar'
    compile 'to.talk.aragorn:commons:0.30-SNAPSHOT@aar'

  }

def coreAarFile = file('build/conman-client.aar')
artifacts {
    archives coreAarFile
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://ci.aws.talk.to:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots",
                    authentication: [
                            userName: 'deployer',
                            password: 'qwedsa'
                    ])
            pom.groupId = 'to.talk.legolas'
            pom.artifactId = 'conman-client'
            pom.version = '1.01-SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }
}
```

When i build the module, it builds successfully. But i dont see the **conman-client.aar** generated. what could be the reason for that?

I read in one of the articles that adding **apply plugin: 'android-library'** to the build.gradle file will produce the .aar file when the module is built.

But this is not happening. what could be the reason for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the plugin:

> apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

if you add an android library module it will be set automatically and when you build it will create an arr file inside build/outputs/arr